# Mopub Android Setup: 'Could not find moat-mobile-app-kit'

Tags: java, android, mopub

## Expected

Building the Android *mopub* library successfully with the configuration outlined in the [Getting Started](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/getting-started/) documentation under the [jcenter](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/getting-started/) implementation.

### Setup

*build.gradle (project)*

Included the **jcenter** and **moat-sdk-builds** libraries.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha09"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gralde (app)*

Included the library **mopub-sdk:5.4.1@aar**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.coinverse"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 15
        versionName "0.15"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding.enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    def paging_version = "2.0.0"
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha09"
    def nav_testing_version = "1.0.0-alpha08"
    def room_version = "2.0.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-rxjava2:$paging_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:5.4.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_testing_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
}
```

## Result

### The result is the following error when building

> Could not find com.moat.analytics.mobile.mpub:moat-mobile-app-kit:2.4.5.
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/Users/adamhurwitz/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.pom
>       file:/Users/adamhurwitz/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.jar
>       file:/Users/adamhurwitz/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.pom
>       file:/Users/adamhurwitz/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.jar
>       file:/Users/adamhurwitz/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.pom
>       file:/Users/adamhurwitz/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.jar
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.pom
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/moat/analytics/mobile/mpub/moat-mobile-app-kit/2.4.5/moat-mobile-app-kit-2.4.5.jar

### Attempted Solution

When `transitive = true` is commented out in Gradle the app builds, runs, and the *mopub* library is present under the external libraries section.

**Does `transitive = true`need to be enabled? If so, how can I resolve the *Could not find com.moat.analytics.mobile.mpub:moat-mobile-app-kit* error?**

```
implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:5.4.1@aar') {
    //transitive = true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue Fixed With Latest MoPub Version

Find the latest version of MoPub in the documentation [here](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/get-started/#step-1-download-the-mopub-android-sdk).

*build.gradle* (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    }
}
```

*build.gradle* (app)

```
dependencies {
    def mopub_version = '+@aar'
    implementation("com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-static:$mopub_version") { transitive = true }
    implementation("com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-video:$mopub_version") { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mopub.mediation:facebookaudiencenetwork:5.1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:ads:11.4.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.4.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.mopub.mediation:flurry:11.4.0.0'
}
```

## Deprecated Solution

I've found the solution in the [*Twitter Community Forumn*](https://twittercommunity.com/t/gradle-sync-error-while-fetching-moat-mobile-app-kit/107792/8?) thanks to @wacamoe.

> Step 1) In gradle-wrapper.properties, ensure you are using `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`
>
> Step 2) Ensure that in your application’s gradle script, you have
> `maven { url “https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds 26” }` in both the buildscript and allprojects sections.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended as per the Mopub's offical documentation.

It clearly states -

> To add the mopub-sdk dependency, open your project and update the app module’s build.gradle.

```
repositories {
    // ... other project repositories
    jcenter() // includes the MoPub SDK and AVID library
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
}
```

It clearly mentions to add the dependency in the module-level as oppose to project-level.

For more information on how to add kindly check the link [here](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/get-started/#step-1-download-the-mopub-android-sdk)

A similar issue discussion suggest to update to the latest version which is 5.8 currently and recommended.- [Check here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/issues/341)

I tried to update the MoPub sdk to the latest with recommended steps and it builds successfully.

My module level gradle is as follows.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs-aar'
        }
    }

   dependencies {

   //MoPub
    implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:5.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
   //   exclude module: 'moat-mobile-app-kit' // To exclude Moat
    }
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:mopub:5.8.0.0'
   }
```

Note:  I have commented exclude module statement just to show that it is working while not using the exclude statement otherwise I have removed it from my gradle file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Hiten. How is your solution different from the answer on [1/5/19](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057021/2253682)? Take a look at the link in that answer which provides an answer from Twitter's team directly. Both are following the documentation's guide.

Comment: Hi Adam,It is different in the sense you have to define
maven { url “https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds 26” } in two places in the application's gradle as per your answer,

But in mine you just need to define it once in the module's gradle file and is as per official MoPub documentation.

Comment: As you stated, the most recent version of MoPub appears to have resolved needing `maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }` declared in both the `buildscript` and `allProjects` of the project _build.gradle_. I've updated the answer accordingly.